# Why am I getting a StackOverflowError exception in my constructor

Tags: java, stack-overflow

```
public class Cloning {

    Cloning c=new Cloning();
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Cloning c=new Cloning();
        c.print();
    }

    public void print(){
        System.out.println("I am in print");
    }

}
```

In the above code I have a simple class and a class level instance, I also have a local instance with the same name. When running the above code I get below exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.java8.Cloning.<init>(Cloning.java:6)
```

Comment: This looks like an attempt to implement a Singleton pattern.  There are a number of ways of doing that.  Do a search for Java Singleton and you'll find many examples.

Comment: Nice Q to ask on StackOverflow!  You should add "no pun intended" ;).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your main method creates a `Cloning` instance (`Cloning c=new Cloning();`), which causes the initialization of the instance variable `c` (`Cloning c=new Cloning();`), which creates another `Cloning` instance, and so on...

You have an infinite chain of constructor calls, which leads to `StackOverflowError`.

> In the above code I have a simple class and a class level instance

You don't have a class level instance. You have an instance level instance. If you want a class level instance, change

```
Cloning c=new Cloning();
```

to

```
static Cloning c=new Cloning();
```

Comment: Actually I *think* the culprit is the creation of the non-`static` `Cloning` instance outside `main`.

Comment: @Bathsheba Well, the original instance is created by the main method. Without that instantiation, no instance variable would be initialized, so the chain of infinite constructor calls wouldn't start. I agree that the bug is probably in not declaring the instance variable as static (which seems to be what the OP wanted).

Comment: Also not sure why we're instantiating `Cloning` both inside *and* outside `main()`.  Surely only one of them is needed.

Answer (score 7):

You instantiate the class `Cloning` every time `Cloning` is constructed, which causes a recursion on instantiations.

Answer (score 7):

Didn't you mean to write `static Cloning c = new Cloning();` *outside* `main`, *or* `c = new Cloning();` *within* `main` instead?

Otherwise, you'll get a new instance of `c` each time this is run, which will cause a `StackOverflowError`.

Currently the creation of the local `c` in `Cloning c = new Cloning();` (which *shadows* the field `c`) kicks the whole thing off.